# No Amazon Cloudsearch results returned if stopwords are included in the query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

When querying Amazon Cloudsearch using the exact content of a field as the query, Cloudsearch returns no results, if the query (and content) contains a stopword. If I remove the stopword from the query, then results are returned.

I understand that stopwords are removed from content when indexing for performance, but I would have thought they would also be ignored in queries to prevent this behavior.

To allow the verbose user to get expected results, will I need to filter out the stopwords from the query for every language, or is there a way for Cloudsearch to ignore stopwords in the query itself?

Index field content:

```
The Company Search Test
```

**Example queries**

With stopword:

```
Query: the company search test
Results: NONE
```

Without stopword:

```
Query: company search test
Results: YES
```

Inside quotes:

```
Query: "the company search test"
Results: YES
```

Implementation details for this example:

- index field type: "text"
- index field analysis scheme: "English"
- all options selected for field: "Return", "Sort", "Highlight"
- QueryParser: "simple"
- using test search in AWS dashboard (same results if using Go sdk)

Comment: Hi. I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you manage to fix this? 
Thx

Comment: Moved on to some other problems, but will be coming back to this... so no clear solution yet.

Comment: Thx. In my case it was caused by some fields not using the same Analysis Scheme, and so not having the same Stopwords. When searching only by a specific field it worked, but searching all the fields (without saying which) did not work

Comment: @carlosvini, it looks like the solution may be simply specifying "OR" as the default operator when querying. Still seems to be a bug with the "AND" as default operator.

Comment: I had this problem too, but in my case, I was setting the query options search fields to include all text, text-array, literal, and literal-array fields. By removing the literal/literal-array fields, from the fields to search on, I got the expected set of results.